# Feedback on implementation of function which compares integer signs in Python

Tags: python, sign

I've made a small function which, given a tuple, compares if all elements in this tuple is of the same sign.

E.g., tuple = `[-1, -4, -6, -8]` is good, while `[-1, -4, 12, -8]` is bad. I am not sure I've made the smartest implementation, so I know this is the place to ask.

```
def check_consistent_categories(queryset):
    try:
        first_item = queryset[0].amount

        if first_item < 0:
            for item in queryset:
                if item > 0:
                    return False
            return True
        else:
            for item in queryset:
                if item < 0:
                    return False
            return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: You need to show us more code. What's queryset? As of right now, it doesn't make sense. You're first_item is of type queryset[0].amount, and you're comparing that sign to that of queryset[i]

Comment: Those don't look like tuples to me.

Comment: What should happen if one member is 0?

Comment: Why the `try...except AnyExceptionIncludingCtrlCAndSystemExit`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might help you:

```
def all_same_sign(ints):
    return all(x < 0 for x in ints) or all(x > 0 for x in ints)
```

You may want to change < and > to <= and >= depending on how you want to treat 0.

Comment: +1 I keep wondering why so many <=5-lines-ish functions posted here are beaten by perfectly readable oneliners. Is it because Python rules, or is is it because some people aren't enlightened yet? (Hint: That's not an xor).

Comment: +1: This is efficient, very clear, and also flexible, in terms of how zero is handled!

Comment: The beautiful, Pythonic thing about this solution is that `all()` short-circuits, stopping when it hits a `False` result, *and* you're using a generator expression rather than a list comprehension, so this function will do at most one complete traversal of the input list, and possibly less, even though it looks like it does exactly two. Nice.

Comment: @delnan: I'm pretty sure it's because Python rules. And I'm pretty sure Python rules because it includes a lot of useful functional-style programming tools.

Comment: This solution needs to iterate twice through the iterable.  This will work for lists (or tuples, per questioners original intent), but not generators or streams.  E.g.  all_same_sign(iter(range(-10, 10))) evaluates to True.

Comment: @tcarobruce: +1 You're right, well spotted. My fix is to change the parameter name to `ints` and to say yes this should only be used on tuples, lists, etc. I can think of a few ways to fix it to work on general iterables, but each solution I thought of either hurts performance, readability or flexibility of handling zero in different ways (e.g. disallow / allow and ignore / treat as positive).

Comment: If you change the all_same_sign(ints) function to `return not(any(x < 0 for x in ints) and any(x > 0 for x in ints))`, the `all_same_sign(iter(range(-10, 10)))` case is properly handled.

Comment: @Matthew Rankin: But then it doesn't work for `all_same_sign(iter(range(10, -10, -1)))`.

Comment: I would like to thank all contributers, most were indeed viable, but this one worked for my needs. I am sorry for the typos in the code, misuse of exceptions and my missuse of the word tuples instead of lists. All these posts made me learn more than I came for :-)

Answer (score 3):

After @EOL's solution, but works without list indexing or iterating multiple times.

```
def all_same_sign(sequence):
    items = iter(sequence)
    try:
        first = items.next() > 0
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return all((item > 0) == first for item in items)
```

This also occurred to me, but doesn't take advantage of all/any short-circuiting:

```
def all_same_sign(sequence):
    return len(set(item > 0 for item in sequence)) <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice pythonic way of doing this (using `all()`):

```
from math import copysign

sign = lambda x: copysign(1, x)  # Sign function

def check_consistent_categories(sequence):
    main_sign = sign(sequence[0])
    return all(sign(y) == main_sign for y in sequence)
```

(for Python 2.6+, which introduced the `math.copysign()` function).  This solution considers that 0 is positive.

Mark Byers' solution is more flexible, though, and it is also arguably more legible.

Comment: +1 to counter downvote. Yes, using `lambda` doesn't equal pythonic (there's a bug in EOL's code, though: should be `lambda x: copysign(1, x)`), but it's a good solution.

Comment: Thank you, @delnan.  Using `lambda` does indeed not make any solution pythonic!  However, using a single line for such a simple function is arguably legible enough, and therefore pythonic enough.  Furthermore, using `all()` is really what made me say that this solution is pythonic, because `all()` is a useful and powerful Python function.

Comment: It works, but Mark Byers is so much more readable and understandable, so you only get a +0. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just one unrelated nit, since you are doing this:

```
try:
    [...]
except:
    [...]
```

You are ignoring `all` of the exceptions, be very careful my friend, this will be hiding lots of bugs, instead always be precise while doing exception handling e.g:

```
try:
    [...]
except IndexError:
    # Handle out of index
except IOError:
    # Handle I/O error
```

etc. Keep this in mind while coding a larger python application.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take advantage of the fact that if all numbers are the same sign, then the sum of the absolute value of each individual number will be equal to the absolute value of the sum of each number?

```
def check_sign(queryset):
    return abs(sum(queryset)) == sum(map(abs, queryset))
```

### Example Showing Details of the Math

**Case 1:** All numbers have the same sign

```
a = (-1, -4, -8)
sum(a) = -13
abs(sum(a)) = 13        # the absolute value of the tuple's sum
map(abs, a) = [1, 4, 8]
sum(map(abs, a)) = 13   # the tuple's sum of each element's absolute value
```

Both methods yield 13, so the signs are the same.

**Case 2:** Not all numbers have the same sign

```
b = (-1, 4, 8)
sum(b) = 11
abs(sum(b)) = 11        # the absolute value of the tuple's sum 
map(abs, b) = [1, 4, 8]
sum(map(abs, b)) = 13   # the tuple's sum of each element's absolute value
```

The methods yield different numbers (11 and 13), so the signs are not all the same.

Comment: `if <boolean expression>: return True else: return False` argh! `return <boolean expression>`! Also, this is very wasteful compared to most other solutions (traverses the list 3 times!).

Comment: @delnan: Argh is right! Not sure what I was thinking. I've removed the unnecessary return True and return False.

Comment: @delnan: True it is wasteful compared to most other solutions, but one advantage is that it handles the `iter(range(-10, 10))` case that identified by tcarobruce. (See his comment in Mark Byer's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that works fine with generators etc. too

```
def all_same_sign(ints):
    ints = iter(ints)
    first_is_positive = next(ints) > 0
    return all( (x>0) == first_is_positive for x in ints)
```

If `ints` is empty, you get a StopIteration exception.

This version gorups 0 with the negative numbers. Use `>=` if you wish to group with the positive numbers instead

Comment: +1: this is an improvement over my own solution, thanks to the bypassing of `math.copysign`, and the fact that it works on iterators as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_same_sign(iterable):
    # Works with any iterable producing any items that can be compared to zero.
    # Iterates through the input no more than once, and this fact is immediately
    # obvious from the code.
    # Exits as soon as a bad combination has been detected.
    pos = neg = zero = False
    for item in iterable:
        if item > 0:
            pos = True
        elif item < 0:
            neg = True
        else:
            zero = True
        # Adjust the following statement if a different
        # treatment of zero is required.
        # Redundant parentheses added for clarity.
        if (pos and neg) or zero:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: +1 This is clean. It's not the most concise... but it's safe, efficient, simple and flexible. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are sorted you only need to compare the ends. If not you could sort them:

```
def same_sign(numbers):
    numbers = sorted(numbers)
    #if numbers[0]==0: return True                Uncomment if you consider 0 positive
    if numbers[0]*numbers[-1]>0: return True
    return False
```

If you changed this to `>=0` zero would be considered sign neutral. I'm not sure if this is a better implementation than the current answers, but it could be faster for large sets of data.

Comment: It would be *slower* for large sets of data.  The other algorithms are O(n), sorting is O(n log n).

Comment: @Malvolio I guess your right. I forgot how slow sort was. But this would be wicked fast if the numbers are sorted since it consists of one comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Using the principal that multiplying your numbers gives a positive result if they all the same, else negative,

```
import operator

def all_same_sign(intlist):
    return reduce(operator.mul, intlist) > 0

>>> all_same_sign([-1, -4, -6, -8])
True
>>> all_same_sign([-1, -4, 12, -8])
False
```

This doesn't handle zeros though...